# how to configure podsec file swift project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

**i got the Error during the validation of pods.(pod lib lint)**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QuWq.png]

**My Podsec file Configuration is:**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'DrawPDF'
s.version          = '1.0'
s.summary          = 'Draw PDF below of iOS 11'

s.description      = <<-DESC
Draw PDF below of iOS 11
DESC

s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/vishalkalola1/DrawPDF.git'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'vishal patel' => 'vishalkalola196@gmail.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/vishalkalola1/DrawPDF.git', :commit=> "8b6aa147c56d2e1685d4ffb15ed6d689d67f4c4d" }

s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
s.source_files = 'DrawPDF/VTablePDFCreationSwift/VTablePDFCreation/VPDFTableCreation/*.{swift}'

end
```

Comment: Vishal did the answer worked? If you find it then do post the answer

Comment: yes its correct but one issue came in after install pods in project. :

My class is download in pods and got reference of the that but all function cant seen in my framework. in class all functions are there.

Comment: Whats the issue?

Comment: check my edited ans

Comment: ' only public var DrawPDFVersionNumber: Double
open class VPDFTableCreation : NSObject {

    public init()

    public func CreatePDFAndSaveDocumentDirectory(pdfName: String, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)
} '

Comment: You need to add **open** access specifier in front of class name. Check my edited answer

Comment: thanks i got it. @NavneetGill

Comment: Great... please do accept the answer if you feel you have got your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Git sources should specify a tag - Add a tag to your code. Since you can see 1.0 being the version specified in **s.version** is **1.0** so **push tag 1.0**.
2. The description should be lengthier than the summary so add some more content to it.
3. If you haven't added your files to the **classes** directory then do so and specify all the added files in **podsec** under **s.source_files**
4. You need to add the **LICENSE** file if you haven't.

**Edit:**

If you have any class in you files then you need to add **open** access specifier and also have to add it to all the overridden method.
You can add **open** just like **public** or **private**